User Access Roles deleted once anograph was restarted
I have installed anzograph 3.1 with frontend. I have created users and assigned them roles. When anzograph was stopped and then started using below commands

sudo systemctl stop anzograph


sudo systemctl start anzograph

On logging in frontend, the user access roles were missing, as exception was thrown
"user_1" doesnt not have SELECT role on "graphname"
Is this  default behaviour  in anzo graph , or we can persist the roles the using some config property
